# Probability with two uniformly distributed random variables.

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Let us assume that $X\sim U(0, 1)$ and $Y\sim U(0, 1)$.

Calculate the following probability:
$$
P(X^2\geq Y)
$$

I have no idea how to start calculating this exression when I have two random variables in it.

Comment: Bayes' theorem.

Comment: $$P(X^2\ge Y) = \iint_{[0,1]\times[0,1]} 1_{\{X^2\ge Y\}}(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

- Draw the square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$.
- Draw the curve $y=x^2$ in this square.
- Find the region where $y \leq x^2$.

Comment: So the answer is $\frac{1}{3}$. Amazing solution. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. :-)